# Combining PowerShell Commands

Tags: powershell

I've written two scripts that give me the independent output that I need, but am not sure how to put them together to give me the combined output.

Returns the count of all of the active users in a particular OU

```
(Get-ADUser -searchbase "OU=OU, DC=domain, DC=com" -filter * |Where {$_.enabled -eq "True"}).count
```

Returns the OU's underneath the same above OU that have "string" in the description property.

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -searchbase "OU=OU, DC=domain, DC=com" -filter * -Properties description | where {$_.description -eq "string"}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is for the script to give me a count of all of the active users underneath the OU's that have "string" in the description property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the easiest way to achieve your goal

```
$OUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -searchbase "OU=OU, DC=domain, DC=com" -filter * -Properties description | where {$_.description -eq "string"}
ForEach ($OU in $OUs) {
    $count = (Get-ADUser -searchbase $OU -filter * | Where {$_.enabled -eq "True"}).count
    Write-Host "OU $OU has $count users"
}
```

the result will be

```
OU OU=foo,DC=domain,DC=com has 6 users
OU OU=Computers,OU=foo,DC=domain,DC=com has 0 users
OU OU=Users,OU=foo,DC=domain,DC=com has 6 users
OU OU=Groups,OU=foo,DC=domain,DC=com has 0 users
```

Answer (score 1):

[Sergio Tanaka's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54914657/45375) works well; let me complement it with a **performance improvement**:

You can **greatly speed up your command by filtering *at the source***, by passing the filter criterion as a **`-Filter` argument** instead of retrieving all objects first and then filtering them with a separate `Where-Object` call:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase 'OU=OU, DC=domain, DC=com' `
                        -Filter  'Description -eq "string"' -Properties description |   #`
  ForEach-Object {
    $count = (Get-ADUser -SearchBase $_ -Filter 'Enabled -eq $true').Count
  }
```

Note that the **`-Filter`-string syntax of the AD cmdlets *resembles* PowerShell code, but it differs in many important ways** - see [`Get-Help about_ActiveDirectory_Filter`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh531527%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

---

#### The general advantages of using `-Filter`:

On a general note, the same performance improvement can be had with cmdlets for  other PowerShell data providers, such as the one for the filesystem (e.g., `Get-ChildItem`), if they support a `-Filter` parameter:

- A `-Filter` string is applied at the *data source*, which means that PowerShell only receives the *result* of the filtering.

  - Since providers are are implemented in compiled code (and they have access to lower-level internals), this generally makes for much better performance; additionally, in remoting scenarios performance improves by simply having to transfer less data over the network.
- Note that `-Filter` parameters are always *strings* with *provider-specific syntax*, so you must consult the relevant provider/cmdlet documentation.